# Explanation of Gradle build error

Tags: java, android, gradle

What is this error about? I don't understand it.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 1

**PS** My SDK build version is already 22.0.1

Comment: this is not sufficient information to get the idea of problem.. you should try to search first other questions..n then if you don't find.. post question with the code where you think problem is or whatever you tried in code....and provide enough information when you ask question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the writing of the old and new versions of Android Studio. In the file Manifest.xml.

> android: icon = "@ drawable / ic_launcher"

should be replaced by

> android: icon = "@ mipmap / ic_launcher"

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense when looking at the question. Please edit the question so that the answer would make sense. Or you can delete the question.